# Looping through MySQL rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database with 3 tables - `events`,`venues`,`instance`. `events` contains informations on events such as event id, name and description. `venues` contains venue id and venue name. `instance` contains event id, venue id and date.

I perform a join and load the results into an array so I can display the event information on a page using PHP:

```
$eid = $_GET['event_id'];

$q = "SELECT e.event_name, e.event_description, i.venue_id, i.instance_avail, DATE_FORMAT( i.instance_date,  '%M %D, %Y' ) AS DATE
FROM events AS e
INNER JOIN instance AS i ON e.event_id = i.event_id
WHERE e.event_id = $eid";

$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc,$q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

The name and description only appear once on the page so they're easy to display with:

```
echo $row['event_name']
```

However, what I also need to do is display a list of dates sorted by venue, like:

```
**New York**

18th December, 2013
19th January, 2014
21st February, 2013

**Washington, DC**

18th December, 2013
22nd December, 2013
12th March, 2014
```

Can I do this using the existing query, or would it be simpler to write a new query? If so, how? Also, how would I loop it so that I display the venue, then the dates, then the next venue etc?

Comment: If you `ORDER BY` cityname, you can keep the query. While looping over all your entries, check if the cityname is the same as the cityname of the last iteration. If i understand your question correctly at least :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the value of the venue out when it changes. Something like this:-

```
<?php

$eid = $_GET['event_id'];

$q = "SELECT e.event_name, e.event_description, i.venue_id, i.venue_name, i.instance_avail, DATE_FORMAT( i.instance_date,  '%M %D, %Y' ) AS DATE
FROM events AS e
INNER JOIN instance AS i ON e.event_id = i.event_id
WHERE e.event_id = $eid
ORDER BY i.venue_id, i.instance_date";
$cur_venue = 0;
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc,$q);
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $cur_venue = $row['venue_id'];
    echo $row['event_name']."<br />";
    echo $row['venue_name']."<br />";
    echo $row['DATE']."<br />";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        if ($cur_venue != $row['venue_id'])
        {
            $cur_venue = $row['venue_id'];
            echo $row['venue_name']."<br />";
        }
        echo $row['DATE']."<br />";
    }
}

?>
```

Possibly clean it up using a do...while loop:-

```
<?php

$eid = $_GET['event_id'];

$q = "SELECT e.event_name, e.event_description, i.venue_id, i.venue_name, i.instance_avail, DATE_FORMAT( i.instance_date,  '%M %D, %Y' ) AS DATE
FROM events AS e
INNER JOIN instance AS i ON e.event_id = i.event_id
WHERE e.event_id = $eid
ORDER BY i.venue_id, i.instance_date";
$cur_venue = 0;
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc,$q);
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['event_name']."<br />";

    do
    {
        if ($cur_venue != $row['venue_id'])
        {
            $cur_venue = $row['venue_id'];
            echo $row['venue_name']."<br />";
        }
        echo $row['DATE']."<br />";
    } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
}

?>
```

EDIT - Had a play with the test data and the below appears to work.

```
<?php

#------ database connections -------
define('MYSQLHOST','localhost');
define('MYSQLUSER','');
define('MYSQLPASS','');
define('MYSQLDATABASE','test');
define('MYSQLDATABASE_INTERNAL', '');// sf orders database

$dbc = mysqli_connect(MYSQLHOST, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS, MYSQLDATABASE);


$eid = $_GET['course_id'];

$q = "SELECT e.course_name, e.course_description, i.venue_id, v.venue_name, i.instance_avail, DATE_FORMAT( i.instance_date,  '%M %D, %Y' ) AS DATE
FROM courses AS e
INNER JOIN instance AS i ON e.course_id = i.event_id
INNER JOIN venue AS v ON i.venue_id = v.venue_id
WHERE e.course_id = $eid
ORDER BY i.venue_id, i.instance_date";
$cur_venue = 0;
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc,$q) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    echo $row['course_name']."<br />";

    do
    {
        if ($cur_venue != $row['venue_id'])
        {
            $cur_venue = $row['venue_id'];
            echo $row['venue_name']."<br />";
        }
        echo $row['DATE']."<br />";
    } while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
}

?>
```

Comment: This works perfectly - apart from the fact that it doesn't display the first venue or its dates. I have 2 venues in my test database, and it displays the second one only (venue_id=2). EDIT: having added another venue, id=3, it also displays that. So a loop iterator issue?

Comment: Just need to add an echo of the details before the WHERE (I have edited the above now)

Comment: This too works nearly perfectly, but only displays one date in the first venue when there is actually two.

Comment: Ooops. Think it would have put that date out, just for the wrong venue. Need to output the venue prior to the while loop as well. Also added a slightly different variation using do...while (not tested). This removes a couple of repeated lines of code.

Comment: Again it works, but still only outputs one date for the first venue. It outputs multiple dates for the other two, just not the first one. :)

Comment: Can you post the table declares and sample data and I will have a play. I must have missed something minor but can't spot it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42862/discussion-between-elendilthetall-and-kickstart)

Comment: For some reason using `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` in the initial PHP causes the strange 'first date missing' error, but I need it to access the rest of the information in the query.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array gets  a row from the recordset and moves the pointer along 1 record in the recordset. So call it the first time and you get the 1st record, and the next time the 2nd record. Hence in my code it is used in an IF to get the first record and to put out the header (for the course name), then in a do....while to get the subsequent records. The do...while gets the next record at the end of the loop, hence its first time through it is using the record from the IF.

Comment: Right. I've fixed it by changing the parameter in the first If loop to simply '$row'. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Mysql` GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT 
    e.event_name, 
    e.event_description, 
    i.venue_id, 
    i.instance_avail, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT( i.instance_date,  '%M %D, %Y' )) AS DATE
FROM events AS e
INNER JOIN instance AS i ON e.event_id = i.event_id
WHERE e.event_id = $eid
GROUP BY e.event_id
```

This will give you all dates comma seperated which can be exploded to an array in php.